# i just want to return data from csv but im always return null

Tags: ios, csv, nsarray

Sorry for my Bad English but i do these for three days can anyone help me plz?

I am newbie xcode programmer and I just want to return data from my csv file but its always null

I try to read many post here. I copy it and edit again and again but it doesn't work.

.

Data in my csv file

```
INTEL Core-i3 3220 3.3 HD2500,x,
AMD FX9590 4.7 8core Black Edition,x,
INTEL Core i3-4130 3.4 HD4400,x,
AMD FX9370 4.4 8core,x,
INTEL Core i3-4330 3.5 HD4600,x,
AMD FX8350 4.0 8core,x
```

this is my NSObject

```
@synthesize cpuData,selectedCpu;
NSMutableArray *x;
-(NSArray *)sendCpu{
    NSArray *itemArray;
    NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"xcpu" ofType:@"csv"];
    NSString *content =  [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filepath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSArray *arrayfarm = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    for (NSString *item in arrayfarm) {
       itemArray = [item componentsSeparatedByString:@",x"];
        [x addObject:itemArray];
    }
    return [x objectAtIndex:cpuData];
}
@end
```

and this is my viewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
globalData *d = [[globalData alloc]init];
    for (int i=1;i<20;i++){
        [d setCpuData:i];
         NSLog(@"%@",[d sendCpu]);
    } 
}
```

one more question plz can someone tell me how to pick one of data

example i want only

```
"INTEL Core-i3 3220 3.3 HD2500" from "INTEL Core-i3 3220 3.3 HD2500,x"
```

i try to do many way but i can't

thank you for your attention and sorry fro my very bad english

Comment: You never allocate the mutable array for the variable `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing:

```
x = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

If you are not using ARC then you should also release it when you are done:

```
NSArray *result = [x objectAtIndex:cpuData];
[x release];
return result;
```